# jQuery, allow only once to click on dialogue yes button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ajaxq

I am trying to write a jQuery dialogue box, when I click on the 'OK' button the data will be sent every time I click on it.

So, I need it to work only once whether I click it many times or once on 'ok' button.

```
$.dialogue({
                    class: 'big',
                    body: html,
                    yes: {
                        text: 'ok',
                        func: function() {

                            //execute some codes

                    }, //end function
                    },
                    no: {text: 'Cancel'},
                });
```

Comment: Where did you get the "$.dialogue" plugin?

Comment: you have have a `var checker = true; put your code inside if(checker){//code here

checker= false;}`

Comment: Depending on the plugin, it will pass `this` as either the button being clicked or the dialog itself.  If it's the button, you can do: `func: function() { $(this).hide();`  (or disable it, depending on how it creates the "button").

Comment: Or just add a flag `if (clicked) return; clicked=true;`

Comment: now it is posting data with the times I click \/_\/

Comment: this.hide() is not working,still post many time as I click on it, I want to control the yes : please help me.

Comment: I am learning old project and the jquery in it is jquery.1.7.2.min.js

Comment: Please post enough of your code to allow us to recreate your problem; including the JavaScript/jQuery, relevant HTML and CSS. Please red the "*[MCVE]*" guidelines, which will explain what we need to see, and why.

Comment: Thanks you very much, For your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.dialogue({
                    class: 'big',
                    body: html,
                    yes: {
                        text: 'ok',
                        func: (function() {
                            var executed = false;
                            return function () {
                            if (!executed) {
                            executed = true;
                            //execute some codes                                                            
                        }
                        };
                    })(), //end function
                    },
                    no: {text: 'Cancel'},
                });
```